# My flutter app isnt working with logo on splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd4f3.png)Hello I am trying to change my splash screen in flutter on vscode using the native way but I keep running to an error and I tried every single solution on the Internet but its not getting resolved I hope someone can help me.
[xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW4qD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put ur image is drawable. use it here instead

1. main/android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml

```dart
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo</item>
    </style>>
```

2. main/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```dart
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo</item>
    </style>
```